# Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Sorry i am new in android

I have 2 **EditTexts** and 1 **button** i am going to when i push the button the value of EditTexts be printed, but i give the error

The XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="212dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="52dp"
        android:layout_y="337dp"
        android:text="@string/Submit"
        android:onClick="submit" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="9dp"
        android:layout_y="86dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Unit"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="15dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
   </EditText>
```

The Java class is:

```
    public class add extends Activity
    {

        private static  String[] montharray; 

        Button   mButton;

        EditText Unit;
        EditText quantity;

        private int days;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add);

            Unit          =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit);
            quantity      =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            mButton       =(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        }  



        public void submit(View view) 
        {


            System.out.println("Unit=    "+Unit.getText().toString()+"   quantity=   "+quantity.getText().toString());  


        }
}
```

Here is thr errors:

```
05-16 15:37:35.857: E/AndroidRuntime(17951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 15:37:35.857: E/AndroidRuntime(17951): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
...


05-16 15:37:35.857: E/AndroidRuntime(17951): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 15:37:35.857: E/AndroidRuntime(17951): at net.learn2develop.UsingIntent.add.submit(add.java:56)
```

I initiate all the objects, what is the  **java.lang.NullPointerException**?

Comment: What is `Unit.getText()` ?  What does it return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the id's are case sensitive...

you should do: `findViewById(R.id.Unit);`

Answer (score 0):

`Unit` is capitalized here

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Unit"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="11dp"
    android:layout_y="15dp"
    android:ems="10" >
```

but not in your code

```
Unit          =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit);
```

You should change it in your xml to lowercase. Also, you should follow a standard for naming conventions. Class names should be camelcased (All words start with capital letter) and variable names should be mixedcase (start with lowercase and capitalize following words i.e `String mixedCase;`) This isn't necessary but it will most likely cause you grief in the future. It also makes it easier for others to understand what you have.